# Are typical sets larger, when information is messier?

Tags: probability-theory, sets, information-theory

Let $0\le q<p\le \frac{1}{2}$, and let $P,Q$ be two Bernoulli Random Variables such that:
$$Pr[P=1]=p ; Pr[P=0]=1-p$$ and $$Pr[Q=1]=q ; Pr[Q=0]=1-q$$
**My question:** Does it follow that, for any $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ as large as desired $|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)|<|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)|$? I.e., that the [Typical Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_set) of $P$ is larger than that of $Q$?

Intuitively, I would say **yes** because of $q<p\le \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow H(q)<H(p)$, and that the "messier" the information (i.e., the higher the entropy), the more elements in the *Typical Set*, but I've been unable to prove this.

**What I've tried:**

- Working with typical sets size bounds, namely that: 
  $(1-\epsilon)2^{n(H(q)-\epsilon)}\le|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)|\le2^{n(H(q)+\epsilon)}$. I was able to prove that $2^{-n(H(p)-\epsilon)}<2^{-n(H(q)-\epsilon)}$ and $2^{-n(H(p)+\epsilon)}<2^{-n(H(q)+\epsilon)}$, but that seems like a dead end.
- Proving that $A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)\subsetneq A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)$ but that's false.
- Finding an Injective Function: $f:A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)\rightarrow A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)$ but couldn't find one.

Comment: Interesting question! It may be better suited to [mathematics.SE], though; if you don't get useful answers after a few days and want us to migrate your question there, please raise a flag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, it can be [shown](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-441-information-theory-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_441S10_lec03.pdf) that:
$$(1-\epsilon)2^{n(H(q)-\epsilon)}\le|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)|\le2^{n(H(q)+\epsilon)}$$
And similiarly:
$$(1-\epsilon)2^{n(H(p)-\epsilon)}\le|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)|\le2^{n(H(p)+\epsilon)}$$
So in order to prove what we wanted, it's enough to find some $\epsilon_0>0$ and $n_0$ such that for all $\epsilon<\epsilon_0, n>n_0$: 
$$2^{n(H(q)+\epsilon)}<(1-\epsilon)2^{n(H(p)-\epsilon)}$$
Let $d:=H(P)-H(Q)>0$, $\epsilon_0:=\frac{d}{2}$.
**Claim:** The above holds for all $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ and $n$ large enough such that $n>\frac{log(1-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon-d}$. Proof:
$$2^{n(H(q)+\epsilon)}<(1-\epsilon)2^{n(H(p)-\epsilon)}\iff$$
$$log(\frac{2^{n(H(q)+\epsilon)}}{(1-\epsilon)})<log(2^{n(H(p)-\epsilon)})\iff$$
$$nH(q)+n\epsilon-log(1-\epsilon)<nH(p)-n\epsilon\iff$$
$$2n\epsilon-nd<log(1-\epsilon)\iff$$
$$n>\frac{log(1-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon-d}$$
Because the last inequation holds (by definition), so does the first, and that is Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$
A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P) = \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \{0,1\}^n : 2^{-n(h(p)+\epsilon)} \leq p^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} (1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)} \leq 2^{-n(h(p)-\epsilon)} \right\}.
$$
We can rephrase the condition as follows. First, it is equivalent to
$$
2^{-n(h(p)+\epsilon+\log(1-p))} \leq \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \leq 2^{-n(h(p)-\epsilon+\log(1-p))}.
$$
Taking the logarithm, we obtain
$$
-n(h(p)+\epsilon+\log(1-p)) \leq \log_2 \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq -n(h(p)-\epsilon+\log(1-p)).
$$
This means that
$$
|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)| = 2^n \Pr\left[\frac{n(h(p)-\epsilon+\log(1-p))}{\log \frac{1-p}{p}} \leq \mathrm{Bin}(n,1/2) \leq \frac{n(h(p)+\epsilon+\log(1-p))}{\log \frac{1-p}{p}}\right]
$$
In order to estimate the probability on the right, we need to use *binomial tail bounds*. The Chernoff bounds is a well-known upper bound, and there are almost matching lower bounds, see for example (1) and (3) in Pelekis, [A lower bound on binomial tails: an approach via tail
conditional expectations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.06651.pdf). Plugging these bounds, we would get a rather accurate estimate for $|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(P)|$, which we could then compare with $|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(Q)|$, estimated using the same method.

Unfortunately, this calculational method seems like a lot of work, better done with the aid of a computer algebra system, and I am not motivated enough to actually carry it through. However, it seems likely (if not certain) that this method will be able to settle the conjecture.